# Unescape XML tags only. Keep content escaped

Tags: java, regex

I have to consume a WS that sends its XML data inside a CDATA tag, the output I get is the following:

```
&lt;parent>
    &lt;child1>
        &lt;xmltag1>4 aÃ±os &lt; 8 &lt;/xmltag1>
        &lt;xmltag2>3 aÃ±os &lt; 12 &lt;/xmltag2>
    &lt;child1>
&lt;/parent>
```

I have to format this data to an usable XML so I can work with it.

It should look like:

```
<parent>
    <child1>
        <xmltag1>4 aÃ±os &lt; 8 </xmltag1>
        <xmltag2>3 aÃ±os &lt; 12 </xmltag2>
    <child>
</parent>
```

With various java functions like this one i havent got a decent output:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(string);
```

There could be a way of getting that result by using regex, so far I got this, but regex is not my strength:

```
string.replaceAll("&lt;{0}>", "</{0}>");
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `\\w` will not match closing tags like `&lt;/xmltag1>`.

Comment: It looks like this response was a UTF-8 response, but was read as ISO 8859-n.  I assume `aÃ±os` should be `años`.

Comment: `string.replace("&lt;", "<")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
String fixedXml = text.replaceAll("&lt;(/?\\w+(?:\\s[^>]*)?>)", "<$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VgSh9M/2/). *Details*:

- `&lt;` - a `&lt;` string
- `(/?\\w+(?:\\s[^>]*)?>)` - Group 1 (`$1`):

  - `/?` - an optional `/` char
  - `\w+` - one or more word chars
  - `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - an optional sequence of a whitespace char and then any zero or more chars other than `>`
  - `>`  - a `>` char.

Comment: That works perfectly for what I asked! Is there a way for doing it with N ocurrences of  &lt;

Comment: @DavidGonzálezArias Probably you mean `.replaceAll("&lt;(?=/?\\w+(?:\\s[^>]*)?>)", "<")`. Or `.replaceAll("(?:&lt;)+(?=/?\\w+(?:\\s[^>]*)?>)", "<")`.